# Applescript works when output is set to desktop, need output set to Team Drive Folder

Tags: applescript

I have an Applescript to convert a XLSX to XLS. I can get the file from a Google Team Drive (via Drive File Stream), convert and save it to my desktop. When I try to save it to a "Out" folder on a Google Team Drive I get a error.

I believe my output path isn't correct. I've tried different ways to reach the path, with no luck.

Working code saving to Desktop:

```
    set {year:y, month:m, day:d, time:t} to (current date)
    set today to (m as number) & d & y
    set TSCfilein to "Volumes:GoogleDrive:Team Drives:Sales:Customer Service:Inventory Feeds:TSC:In:TSC_Master.xlsx"
    set TSCfileout to (path to desktop as text) & "TSC" & today & ".xls" as string

    tell application "Microsoft Excel"
        activate
        open file TSCfilein
        tell workbook 1
            tell sheet 1
            save active workbook in TSCfileout as Excel98to2004 file format


        end tell

        close without saving
        end tell
    end tell
```

Changing set TSCfileout to the following causes the error:

```
    set TSCfileout to "Volumes:Google Drive:⁨Team Drives⁩:Sales:Customer Service⁩:Inventory Feeds:TSC:Out" & "TSC" & today & ".xls" as string
```

The expected result is to save the file Google Team Drive folder.

Error:

"Microsoft Excel got an error: active workbook of sheet 1 of workbook 1 doesn’t understand the “save” message." when I try to point the output file location.

Comment: In your line of code that produces the error, try changing `"TSC"` to `":TSC"` or `":TSC:"`

Answer (score 0):

There is a general misunderstanding: HFS paths start **always** with a disk name, but never with `Volumes`.

Don't mix it up with POSIX paths.

- The startup volume "Macintosh HD" as POSIX path is `/` as HFS path `Macintosh HD`
- The external volume "Google Drive" as POSIX path is `/Volumes/Google Drive` as HFS path `Google Drive`

And there is a missing colon after `Out`

Your path to the external volume is

```
set TSCfileout to "Google Drive:⁨Team Drives⁩:Sales:Customer Service⁩:Inventory Feeds:TSC:Out:" & "TSC" & today & ".xls"
```

The trailing coercion `as string` is redundant. According to the rules the leftmost type is the result type of a concatenation.